# How do you preselect the options when loading the q-select?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I'm new to vue and quasar so i haven't done this yet. I'm building the ability to edit a record and I want to be able to pre select the options for a q-select element. The pre selected options are what the user saved when they first created the record. Currently I have:

```
<q-select
    v-model="products"
    label="Products *"
    :options="products"
    option-label="title"
    option-value="id"
    multiple
    use-chips
    :rules="[val => val || 'A product is required']"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, You just need to set the model value in your case `products` and it will work.

Example -

```
      model: 'Twitter',
      options: [
        'Google', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Apple', 'Oracle'
      ]
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/QWNBxWz

Comment: I have an array of values, so I just set the array to the model.